# Types and Symbols in Scala reflection API

Tags: scala, reflection

Why converting Type to Symbol and back leads to lose of type information?

Code:

```
println(typeOf[String] <:< typeOf[String])
println(typeOf[String].typeSymbol.info <:< typeOf[String])
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: `s/info/asType.toType/` and you get what you want

Comment: But more generally, you can think of the symbol as the name identifying a (possible) type constructor; so `typeOf[Seq[String]].typeSymbol` is `Seq`.

Answer (score 0):

[Doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Symbols$Symbol) for the `info` says:

> This method always returns signatures in the most generic way
>   possible.

In this case, `info` returns `java.lang.Object` rather than `String` and hence the `false` result.